# MaskFormatter in java

Tags: java, swing

Is there something like `MaskFormatter` but which is uses regular expressions to set the format of `JFormatedTextField`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a custom [Document Filter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for this purpose.